# Confused with logic of my if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
right = 0 
left = 0
if(left > right or (left and right) == 0):
    print 'doing task 1'
else:
    print 'doing task2'
```

for some reason no matter what value I give right or left (for example, if i set right to be 10 and left to be 2)... it always does the "doing task 1" condition.....does anybody know why?

Comment: Tried it, does print "doing task2": https://eval.in/961305

Comment: The expression (left and right) will return 0 when one of the variables equal 0. And will always return right value in any other case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick; you had some issues in your `if` conditions, that's it

```
if((left > right) or (left == 0 and right==0)):
    print('doing task 1')
else:
    print('doing task2')
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use `elif` function

```
right = 0
left = 0
if(left > right):
    print 'doing task 1'
elif left ==0 and right == 0:
    print 'doing task 1'    
else:
    print 'doing task2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
right = 2
left = 1
if(left > right or (right == 0 and left == 0)):
    print 'doing task 1'
else:
    print 'doing task2'
```

I assume you meant to have task 1 show up if either left is greater than right, OR both of right and left are equal to zero.

If you do this

```
(left and right) == 0
```

it is doing a boolean comparison, instead of comparing each of left and right to zero.

see **boolean operations** in the python docs:

section 5.2 as of the time of writing

Answer (score 0):

you probably want

```
if right < left or 0 == left and 0 == right:
    print('doing task 1')
else:
    print('doing task 2')
```

which can be written as

```
print('doing task %d'
      % (1 if right < left or 0 == left and 0 == right else 2))
```